# Mocking promised based request with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a function using Jest, and I'm having some trouble dealing with jest mock modules (the equivalent of rewire or proxyquire in nodejs world).

I'm actually trying to test that a spy has been called on the mocked module with some parameters. Here's the function that I want to test.

NB : the current test only concerns the "fetch(...)" part, I m trying to test that fetch has been called with the good parameter.

```
export const fetchRemote = slug => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loading());
        return fetch(Constants.URL + slug)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(cmp => {
                if (cmp.length === 1) {
                    return dispatch(setCurrent(cmp[0]));
                }
                return dispatch(computeRemote(cmp));
            });
    };
};
```

The function returned acts as a closure, and so "captures" the node-fetch external module that I want to mock.

Here's the test I m trying to make pass green :

```
it('should have called the fetch function wih the good const parameter and slug', done => {
            const slug = 'slug';
            const spy = jasmine.createSpy();
            const stubDispatch = () => Promise.resolve({json: () => []});
            jest.mock('node-fetch', () => spy);
            const dispatcher = fetchRemote(slug);
            dispatcher(stubDispatch).then(() => {
                expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Constants.URL + slug);
                done();
            });
        });
```

EDIT : The first answer helped a lot concerning writing the test, I have now the following one :

```
it('should have called the fetch function wih the good const parameter and slug', done => {
            const slug = 'slug';
            const stubDispatch = () => null;
            const spy = jest.mock('node-fetch', () => Promise.resolve({json: () => []}));
            const dispatcher = fetchRemote(slug);
            dispatcher(stubDispatch).then(() => {
                expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Constants.URL + slug);
                done();
            });
        });
```

But now, here's the error I have :

```
 console.error node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:117
      Unhandled promise rejection [Error: expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

      jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
      Received:
        object: {"addMatchers": [Function anonymous], "autoMockOff": [Function anonymous], "autoMockOn": [Function anonymous], "clearAllMocks": [Function anonymous], "clearAllTimers": [Function anonymous], "deepUnmock": [Function anonymous], "disableAutomock": [Function anonymous], "doMock": [Function anonymous], "dontMock": [Function anonymous], "enableAutomock": [Function anonymous], "fn": [Function anonymous], "genMockFn": [Function bound getMockFunction], "genMockFromModule": [Function anonymous], "genMockFunction": [Function bound getMockFunction], "isMockFunction": [Function isMockFunction], "mock": [Function anonymous], "resetModuleRegistry": [Function anonymous], "resetModules": [Function anonymous], "runAllImmediates": [Function anonymous], "runAllTicks": [Function anonymous], "runAllTimers": [Function anonymous], "runOnlyPendingTimers": [Function anonymous], "runTimersToTime": [Function anonymous], "setMock": [Function anonymous], "unmock": [Function anonymous], "useFakeTimers": [Function anonymous], "useRealTimers": [Function anonymous]}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to return a promise when [testing async code](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content). And your spy needs to return a resolved or rejected promise.

```
it('should have called the fetch function wih the good const parameter and slug', done => {
  const slug = 'successPath';
  const stubDispatch = () => Promise.resolve({ json: () => [] });
  spy = jest.mock('node-fetch', (path) => {
    if (path === Constants.URL + 'successPath') {
      return Promise.resolve('someSuccessData ')
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('someErrorData')
    }
  });
  const dispatcher = fetchRemote(slug);
  return dispatcher(stubDispatch).then(() => {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Constants.URL + slug);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't see the spy in this implementation :/. But thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you tried `expect(spy.mock)` instead of `expect(spy)`?

Comment: And you have to return the dispatcher from your test.

Comment: I've tried but no way. And it seems that the node-module isn't mocked at all. When I run my test without my backend, it sends the request and throw errors

Comment: Ok, so how do you import `fetch` into your module or do you use the native JS implementation?

Comment: Import fetch from 'node-fetch';

Comment: maybe it helps when you create the mock before importing the file you wanna test